# SQL query sum and inner join

Tags: sql

I have been asked the following during an interview (which as you may guess reading the question was for a company working in the finance industry):

---

Let's suppose you have the 2 following table

```
Create table SHARES(
    SHAREID   NUMBER(10) not null,
    NAME      VARCHAR2(40) not null));

Create table DEALS(
    DEALID    NUMBER(10) not null,
    SHAREID   NUMBER(10) not null,
    QUANTITY  NUMBER(10,4),
    PRICE     NUMBER(10,4));
```

Give a SQL query to display your positions (by summing deals). This query should return the following information : share name, quantity.

---

First of all, I am not even sure that I understood what was asked but what I understood so far is that we want to display a list like that:

```
SHARENAME POSITION(=Sum(for each deals of this share){dealsquantity*price}
```

So my answer was:

```
Select Name, SUM(Quantity * Price) 
FROM SHARES Inner Join DEALS on SHARES.SHAREID = DEALS.SHAREID
Group by NAME
```

I did not get to know if the answer was correct or not, but I think it is just wrong.
So I would like to know if you have any suggestion/correction to do.

Thanks

PS: I think I anyway need to study back the whole SQL thing

Thanks

Comment: Looks fine (although I only know the "you're understanding of the problem"--> SQL side of things, can say if your Positions understanding is right). They didn't give you any feedback?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic though because it is about the [Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/?as=1) or maybe [Codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If you stated the question exactly as they did, then you are correct.

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess I was so unsure because it has been a while since I have done such thing.

And no, no feedback because we were urged to finish ASAP for the next interview. And yes I think it should go to Codereview (which I never heard of before), but I guess there is not as many people on it  as on SO ?